# MySQL multiple AND statement conditions - CakePHP

Tags: mysql, sql, cakephp

Only the 2nd of the two AND statements are reading for me. I believe I am running into a nesting issue, but not sure at this point:

```
...'conditions' => array(
            "AND" => array(
                array($ApplicantAge . ' BETWEEN Age.Min_Age AND Age.Max_age'),
                'Zips.title'       => $Zip,
                'Applicant.amount' => array($comboType, $memberCount)
            ),
            "AND" => array(
                array($PsSpouseAge . ' BETWEEN Age.Min_Age AND Age.Max_age'),
                'PlanDetail.company_id' => '27',
                'Zips.title'            => $Zip,
                'Applicant.amount'      => array($comboType, $memberCount)
            )
        ),...
```

As you can see I am trying to get ALL records **$ApplicantAge . ' BETWEEN Age.Min_Age AND Age.Max_age** AND ONLY specific records **WHERE 'PlanDetail.company_id' => '27** AND  **$PsSpouseAge . ' BETWEEN Age.Min_Age AND Age.Max_age'),**...

Here is my SQL output:

```
WHERE ((18 BETWEEN `Age`.`Min_Age` AND `Age`.`Max_age`) OR (`Zips`.`title` = '98605') OR (`Applicant`.`amount` IN ('as', '2'))) AND ((24 BETWEEN `Age`.`Min_Age` AND `Age`.`Max_age`) AND (`PlanDetail`.`company_id` = 27) AND (`Zips`.`title` = '97378') AND (`Applicant`.`amount` IN ('as', '2')))
```

As it stands, the **'PlanDetail.company_id' => '27'**, is overriding and only the results that meet this **'PlanDetail.company_id' => '27'** criteria are showing

I've been at this for a while, so its all starting to mash up in eye view.. Thanks for noting any problems with my SQL logic.

**Here is my full joins and conditions now:**

```
 $options = array(
        'joins'      => array(
            array(
                'table'      => 'plans_zips',
                'alias'      => 'PZips',
                'type'       => 'inner',
                'foreignKey' => false,
                'conditions' => array('Plan.id = PZips.plan_id')
            ),
            array(
                'table'      => 'zips',
                'alias'      => 'Zips',
                'type'       => 'inner',
                'foreignKey' => false,
                'conditions' => array('Zips.id = PZips.zip_id')
            )
        ),
        'conditions' => array(
            'OR' => array(
                'AND' => array(
                    array($ApplicantAge . ' BETWEEN Age.Min_Age AND Age.Max_age'),
                    'Zips.title'       => $Zip,
                    'Applicant.amount' => array($comboType, $memberCount),
                    'NOT'              => array(
                        'PlanDetail.company_id' => 27
                    )
                ),
                array($PsSpouseAge . ' BETWEEN Age.Min_Age AND Age.Max_age')
            )
        ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I was able to get it working this way (and enhanced by adding a second query):**

```
'conditions' => array(
            "OR" => array(
                'AND' => array(
                    $ApplicantAge . ' BETWEEN Age.Min_Age AND Age.Max_age',
                    'Zips.title'               => $Zip,
                    'Applicant.amount'         => array($comboType, $memberCount),
                "NOT" => 
                    array(array('PlanDetail.company_id' => array('27','3')))),
                array(
                    $PsSpouseAge . ' BETWEEN Age.Min_Age AND Age.Max_age',
                    'Zips.title'            => $Zip,
                    'Applicant.amount'      => array($comboType, $memberCount),
                    'PlanDetail.company_id' => '27'),
                array(
                    $OdsSpouseAge . ' BETWEEN Age.Min_Age AND Age.Max_age',
                    'Zips.title'            => $Zip,
                    'Applicant.amount'      => array($comboType, $memberCount),
                    'PlanDetail.company_id' => '3'))
    ),
```

**The resultant SQL is:**

```
WHERE 
((((18 BETWEEN `Age`.`Min_Age` AND
`Age`.`Max_age`) AND
(`Zips`.`title` = '98258') AND
(`Applicant`.`amount` IN ('as', '2')) AND
(NOT (`PlanDetail`.`company_id` IN (27, 3)))))
OR
(((50 BETWEEN `Age`.`Min_Age` AND
`Age`.`Max_age`) AND
(`Zips`.`title` = '98258') AND
(`Applicant`.`amount` IN ('as', '2')) AND
(`PlanDetail`.`company_id` = 27)))
OR
(((50 BETWEEN `Age`.`Min_Age`AND
`Age`.`Max_age`) AND
(`Zips`.`title` = '98258') AND
(`Applicant`.`amount` IN ('as', '2')) AND
(`PlanDetail`.`company_id` = 3))))
```

I am open to any suggested optimization ideas for this. But this is the only way I could get it working.

Answer (score 3):

Array keys are unique, you can't have two `"AND"` keys. This case is [covered in the manual](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1030/Complex-Find-Conditions), just wrap them in another array:

```
array(
    array('and' => array(…)),
    array('and' => array(…))
)
```

Since conditions are `AND` by default though you could leave it out completely. `(a AND b AND c) AND (d AND e AND f)` is the same as `a AND b AND c AND d AND e AND f`.

Looks to me like the condition you posted could be simplified to this:

```
'conditions' => array(
    'Zips.title'            => $Zip,
    'Applicant.amount'      => array($comboType, $memberCount),
    'PlanDetail.company_id' => 27,
    "$ApplicantAge BETWEEN Age.Min_Age AND Age.Max_age",
    "$PsSpouseAge BETWEEN Age.Min_Age AND Age.Max_age"
)
```

---

Apparently you want something like this though:

```
'conditions' => array(
    'or' => array(
        'and' => array(
            "$ApplicantAge BETWEEN Age.Min_Age AND Age.Max_age",
            'Zips.title'       => $Zip,
            'Applicant.amount' => array($comboType, $memberCount),
            'not' => array(
                'PlanDetail.company_id' => 27
            )
        ),
        "$PsSpouseAge BETWEEN Age.Min_Age AND Age.Max_age"
    )
)
```

Comment: I am still experimenting with this, but this is the breakdown of what needs to happen: 1. Get ALL records (WHERE $ApplicantAge . ' BETWEEN Age.Min_Age AND Age.Max_age')  except those where 'PlanDetail.company_id' => '27', then add in records that array($PsSpouseAge . ' BETWEEN Age.Min_Age AND Age.Max_age'). You see there are two age variables.

Comment: @Old So all records *where (age between x - y **and not** company = 27) OR (age between x - y)*?

Comment: @Dec, Yes. You understand correct. I am trying the OR operator, but I cannot get the AND and OR working together.

Comment: @Dec, thanks for the suggestions, but now ALL records are being returned. I am still trying variations. I posted my full joins array above, ALL plans_zips records are being pulled in?? About 115,000 records.

Comment: This is just not making sense. My query is being generated as expected, but NO results will display (seems the values are not being passed to the view now)... Here is my SQL ...WHERE ((19 BETWEEN `Age`.`Min_Age` AND `Age`.`Max_age`) AND (`Zips`.`title` = '97378') AND (`Applicant`.`amount` IN ('as', '2')) AND (NOT (`PlanDetail`.`company_id` = 27))) AND ((22 BETWEEN `Age`.`Min_Age` AND `Age`.`Max_age`) AND (`PlanDetail`.`company_id` = 27)) ORDER BY `monthly_cost` ASC LIMIT 100 ... It seems as if my first query is overwriting my second query thus returning nothing... Yup I am stuck on this!

Comment: Still not solved... I can't seem to get the and/or reading the right way:  'conditions' => array(
             'Zips.title'       => $Zip,
       'Applicant.amount' => array($comboType, $memberCount),
             'AND' => array(
             
               $ApplicantAge . ' BETWEEN Age.Min_Age AND Age.Max_age',
                        'PlanDetail.company_id !=' => '27'),
    'OR' => array(
              
               $PsSpouseAge . ' BETWEEN Age.Min_Age AND Age.Max_age',
                        'PlanDetail.company_id' => '27'),
     ),